# how to display image in a <img> tag whose name is stored in database

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I got the image name inserted in MS SQL Server database. and the images should be displayed in a `ListView` , the question is how to append accurate image path to `src` attribute in code snippet below:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="boxWrapper">
              <img src=<%#Eval("name") %> />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of concatenating additional string with eval statement is below:

```
<img src='<%# "YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH" + Eval("name") %>' />
```

**Eg.**

```
<img src='<%# "content/images/" + Eval("name") %>' />
```

This will fix your concern